# Using the methods of moments in R for the dirichlet distribution

Tags: r, distributions, dirichlet-distribution, method-of-moments

I'm trying to build a distribution of transition probabilities to randomly sample from in a Markov model where individuals can transition from one health state to another (assume that in the image below I am considering the healthy state). I'm aware that in R the method of moments can be used to translate a mean and standard error reported in the literature to an alpha and a beta for use in drawing from the beta distribution, as per the below:

Assume the below mean and std error come from the reported literature

```
mean <- 0.75 
std.error <- 0.04
```

The method of moments can be coded up as below to get the alpha and beta from the sample using the
mean and standard error from the sample:

```
alpha.plus.beta <- mean*(1-mean)/(std.error^2)-1 ## alpha + beta (ab)
alpha <- mean*alpha.plus.beta ## alpha (a)
beta <- alpha*(1-mean)/mean ## beta(b)
```

Following this, you can randomly draw from the beta distribution using the alpha and beta as below:

```
probabilistic.beta.dist.draw <- rbeta(1,alpha,beta)
```

This seems like something that would be quite handy for me in translating transition probabilities from the literature into a distribution I can draw from randomly for a probabilistic sensitivity analysis (I'm a health economist, but basically repeatedly sampling from this distribution).

My question is this, in situations where you can transition out of the state you are in into one of three states, as per the image, is it possible to use the method of moments to translate a set of means and standard errors for transitioning into these states from the literature into values that can be used in a dirichlet distribution as per the below:

```
rdirichlet(1, c(number1, number2, number3))
```

I was thinking that maybe I could apply the method of moments as I do above to each transition probability coefficient and standard error individually for each state individuals can transition into, then add the alpha and beta, and use the alpha.plus.beta for each transition probability in the dirichlet distributon as above. So number1 would be the alpha.plus.beta for the first state you can transition into, and so on for states 2 and 3.

Can someone help me to understand if this approach is OK, and if not, help me to apply a better one in R? Basically, with the option to transition into multiple states, how can I take the mean and std error from the reported literature to make a distribution to sample from?

[image: The Markov model I describe]

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suppose that potentially I could take the mean and the standard error for transition probability into each state from the literature, use the methods of moments on these probabilities individually and then apply the following code to the resultant alpha and beta to get a probability distribution I can draw from. Here I refer to the three states as A, B, C:  `A<- rbeta(1, shape1= 512, shape2=746 )
B<- rbeta(1, shape1= 731, shape2=527 )
C<- rbeta(1, shape1= 15, shape2=1243)
A <- round(A, digits = 2)
B <- round(B, digits = 2)
C <- round(C, digits = 2)
D<- A+B+C #rounded to sum to 1/100%`